# Automatically copy / clone column to other columns in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, clone

I want to automatically fill / clone / copy column `E` (from cell `E8` down to `E100`) to `L8`, `S8`, `Z8` etc.

Is this possible using a formula?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to put `=IF(MOD(COLUMN()-5,7)=0,$E8,"")` in `L8` and copy down to `L100` and then that block across as far as required.

Potentially that is a lot of formulae and these may interfere with subsequent entries such as into `M50`, so I suggest copying the entire range containing the formulae and then Paste Special, Values over the top.

Counting from 1, ColumnL happens to be 7 to the right of ColumnE but also Column 12 to Excel. So in ColumnL COLUMN() [ie 12] -5 is 7. MOD(…,7) will give a residual for any number not divisible by seven but not (ie =0) when that number is a multiple of seven. The `IF` function then takes a copy of `E8` etc where required and inserts a blank (“”) where not.

Answer (score 1):

If you're ok with dragging over all existing columns you can use this formula in F8 and drag across and down:

`=if(MOD(column()-5,7)=0,$e8,"")`

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the column by entering `=IF($E8="","",$E8)` in `L8`, `S8`, and `Z8` and then filling each formula down the column accordingly.